# Teste Unitário Controller Spring com Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Estou tentando testar o método abaixo do meu controller:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/listar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView iniciaTela(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request){

            final ParametroEnvioManualVO parametroEnvioManualVO =  new ParametroEnvioManualVO();
            final PerfilUsuarioLogadoVO perfilUsuarioLogado = (PerfilUsuarioLogadoVO) request
                    .getSession().getAttribute(AbstractConstantes.PERFIL_USUARIO_LOGADO);
            String strCodigoUnidadeUsuario = perfilUsuarioLogado.getNuUnidade();

            parametroEnvioManualVO.setCodigoUnidadeUsuario(strCodigoUnidadeUsuario);
            parametroEnvioManualVO.setNomeUnidadeUsuario(perfilUsuarioLogado.getSgUnidade());
            List<ModeloMensagemUnidadeVO> listaModelos = bean.obterModelosAutorizadosUnidade(Integer.parseInt(strCodigoUnidadeUsuario));
            parametroEnvioManualVO.setListaModelos(listaModelos);

            model.addObject(SESSION_ATTRIBUTES, parametroEnvioManualVO);
            model.setViewName(VIEW_NAME);
            return model;
        }
```

Porém não estou conseguindo simular uma HttpSession pra passar o objeto perfilUsuarioLogado, pois é dele que o controller busca um parâmetro para efetuar a consulta de modelos e devolver para o model.
Estou tentando com o Mockito, mas estou batendo cabeça aqui....
Meu desafio é montar o HttpServletRequest com uma HttpSession dentro e dentro desta o objeto perfilUsuarioLogado como parâmetro.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar o teste unitário você pode utilizar as classes [MockHttpServletRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html)  e [MockHttpSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpSession.html) do Spring.

Para você pegar a idéia, segue um controlador simples:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController(value = "/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public ModelAndView list(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addObject("returnedAttribute", request.getSession().getAttribute("test"));
        return model;
    }
}
```

Aqui estou apenas pegando o atributo `test` da sessão e recolocando no modelo como `returnedAttribute`

Farei um teste unitário simples para validar que o valor que foi passado inicialmente na sessão foi retornado no modelo:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void list() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        ModelAndView returnedModel = controller.list(modelAndView, getMockServletRequest());
        assertEquals("nullptr user on StackOverflow", returnedModel.getModelMap().get("returnedAttribute"));
    }

    private HttpServletRequest getMockServletRequest() {
        MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        mockRequest.setSession(getMockSession());
        return mockRequest;
    }

    private HttpSession getMockSession() {
        MockHttpSession mockSession = new MockHttpSession();
        mockSession.setAttribute("test", "nullptr user on StackOverflow");
        return mockSession;
    }

    @InjectMocks
    private TestController controller;
}
```

Com isso temos um teste passando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado cara.

Mas estou recebendo esse erro abaixo ao tentar instanciar o MockHttpServletRequest():

Comment: Se puder complementar a questão com seu `pom.xml`, parece ser um problema relacionado a um conflito de libs, a noite posto meu `pom.xml` para você dar uma olhada

Comment: Era o mesmo erro que eu estava enfrentando aqui antes de abrir o tópico. Segue link para o pom: https://github.com/andreluizpb/geral/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: O erro é esse:
```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.emptyInput()Ljava/io/InputStream;
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest.<clinit>(MockHttpServletRequest.java:102)
    at xxx.controller.ManterEnvioManualControllerTest.getMockServletRequest(ManterEnvioManualControllerTest.java:110)
```

Comment: Acho que cabe uma nova pergunta para a resolução deste conflito de versões, já que a questão original já foi respondida